# WD MY Book external drive power button broke

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a WD My Book 1TB with a 3.0 USB. This one has an on/off button that has stopped working. I have a Toshiba A505 windows 7. I need to recover everything off of the external. I thought I could take the external drive out of the 1TB, place it in an empty external box, and transfer the files. What kind and size of box do I need to purchase?

Comment: questing seeking product recommendations are off topic at Super USer

Comment: I was not wanting a 'brand', just wanting to know what I needed in specifications. I have taken apart desktops, but not an external. Not driving at the moment, so I have to ask someone to get things for me. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the drive out and plug it into your PC(not laptop) if you have one. You'll need to have the correct connector, probably SATA. Any recent PC should have that connector. Can you not fix the power button at least enough for you to transfer the files? You can also put it into another external harddrive by swapping the drive(again, connectors have to match).

Comment: I tried to get the button to stay on. I have an xp desk top that I can use to send it through to another external, but I did not know if that would work. On the Sata, can I take one off of a dell, the xp is an HP.  I  am a visual learner, when I take the driver out, is there already a Sata, and do I just plug it in the back of the desk top or do I need to plug it in inside? I know they take a lot of power, I have a 2TB and a 3TB.

Comment: All I can tell you is most hard drives are interchangeable because they all follow a standard. So take the hard drive out of your external drive and find a working computer that you can add this drive to. Plug the drive inside, turn on the computer, and more than likely, you will see the drive. If not, then your drive may be bad or a configuration change may be necessary. They do not take a lot of power. It sounds like you need somebody more experienced onsite to help you do this. You don't want to lost your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your information off this HDD you will need to find someone who can fix the power button for you. Most My Book drives have hardware encryption in place that is tied to the controller of the enclosure.

Once you get your data off the HDD you can continue using it even with a different enclosure, the drive itself will work but the data won't be readable, you will have to format it if you want to use it with a different enclosure.

Comment: I took my external drive to a computer place today, they took it out of the enclosure and plugged it into a computer. It would not spin. Not ready to give up yet.

Comment: They did not try to fix the power button.

Comment: Unfortunately if the drive doesn't spin then the problem is not with the power button on the enclosure but the HDD itself. At this point if you need to recover the data you will have to use the services of a professional DR company. Have a look at the list of [WD Data Recovery Partners](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=WQf9ol) they usually offer a discount for WD drives.